# How use Lorentz Gauge in Einstein tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, gauge-invariance, gauge, linearized-theory

i have the Einstein tensor in terms *h* of first order

$$
\begin{eqnarray}  \label {eq: wf5o}
G_{\beta \mu}& = & -\frac{1}{2}\left[ \bar h_{\beta \mu},_{\lambda}^{\;\;,\lambda}+\eta_{\beta\mu}\bar h_{\lambda \sigma} ^{\;\;\;,\lambda\sigma}-\bar h_{\beta\lambda},_{\mu}^{\;\;\lambda}-\bar h_{\mu\lambda}._{\beta}^{\;\; ,\lambda}\right] \\
& &+\mathcal{O} (h^{2})  \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
$$

but if i use the Lorentz Gauge

$$
\begin{equation} \label {eq: wf5p}
\bar h^{\lambda\sigma},_{\sigma}=0
\end{equation}
$$

then the Einstein tensor becomes

$$
\begin{equation} \label {eq: wf5q}
G^{\beta\mu}=-\frac{1}{2} \left( -\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}+\bigtriangledown^{2} \right) \bar h^{\beta\mu}
\end{equation}
$$

how i need to use the Lorentz Gauge so the 1st Eq becomes 3rd eq.?

thanks

Comment: Minor comment: That would be the Lorenz without a "t".

Answer (score 2):

Your gauge condition sets the second, third and fourth terms to zero, thanks to the fact that partial derivatives commute, and raising and lowering indices inside of the partial derivatives can be done for free, up to terms of order $h^{2}$.  This leaves you with:

$$G_{\mu \nu} = -\frac{1}{2}h_{\mu \nu, \lambda}{}^{\lambda}$$

And then, your result folows, because, for any $\phi$:

$$\phi_{,\alpha}{}^{\alpha} = -\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}\phi + \sum_{i} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial (x^{i})^{2}}\phi = -\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}\phi + \nabla^{2}\phi$$

And there's your result.